# CSS and HTML change after value and type of link

Tags: html, css, button, hover, dotnetnuke

I'm working in Dot Net Nuke on a website that has been previously setup. I want to add a css button I found on the internet. I put the html in the html fields and css in the stylesheet editor.

when a link is created it automatically adds ">>" after the link text. In other buttons css buttons I used I managed to remove that, but with this button I can't remove it. Also I want the button to link to another page using "a href". How would i make this possible?

Button HTML:

```
<div class="btn-container">
    <input type="submit" value="button" id="button-blue"/>
    <div class="ease"></div>
</div>
```

Button CSS:

```
#button-blue {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    border: white solid 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #0493bd;
    margin-top: -4px;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: .1em;
    padding-top: 22px;
    padding-bottom: 22px;
    font-weight: 500;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

/* Change text color & background opacity on hover*/
#button-blue:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    color: #0493bd;
 }

/* The white hover effect */
.ease {
    width: 0px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease;
   -moz-transition: .3s ease;
    -o-transition: .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: .3s ease;
    transition: .3s ease;
}

/* Make visable when hover */
.btn-container:hover .ease {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 0;
}

.btn-container:after {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: can you send complete code or snippet?

Comment: This is all the code used for this button

Answer (score 1):

well you want the button to link to another page, to do that you can simply style your href to look as a button like this (Run the following snippet) -

```html
<a href = "#" id ="submit-btn">Submit</a>
    
<style>          
   #submit-btn{
      display :inline-block;
      text-decoration:none;
      background-color:blue;
      border-radius:4px;
      padding:5px 10px;
      color:white;
    }
</style>
```

Well for the issue of `>>` after every link it may be some css that is adding it, which you haven't posted in your question so try adding following code which may remove it..

```
a:after {
   content: none !important;
}
```

OR this one -

```
a:after {
   display: none !important;
}
```

or just for the link like button I posted above try this -

```
#submit-btn:after {
   content: none !important;
 }
```

OR

```
#submit-btn:after {
   display: none !important;
}
```

**NOTE** - Since you are overwriting CSS don't forget to add `!important`..

Comment: what about second issue? ">>"

Comment: well for that issue we need to look at the code to see why it adds >> after every link, so that it can removed using the right code than..

Comment: The >> is added using CSS that was created by the website developer. I do not have the rights to change specifically that code, but I can override it with the stylesheet editor I use to put my CSS in. Basically all CSS code I put in there for classes that allready exist will be overriden.

Comment: did you tried what i suggested above?? i.e. removing everything using (:after)

Comment: Still trying the different methods you suggested. Give couple minutes to try different ways. btw I can't put the CSS inline with the html. It has to be put in a seperate editor in order to override existing CSS

Comment: yes even I would suggest to use an external CSS , My answer was a suggestion to code that way..

Comment: I would also suggest to check the code using INSPECT ELEMENT to see on what tag the css for >> is applied..

Comment: using     #button-blue:after {
       content: none !important;
    } will remove the >>. But the layout is still wrong. How would I remove that? would text-decoration: none; work?

Answer (score 0):

Change to button to `href`

```
<div class="btn-container">
   <a href="#" id="button-blue">Button</a>
   <div class="ease"></div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
#button-blue{
float:left;
width: 100%;
max-width:500px;
border: white solid 4px;
cursor: pointer;
background-color: #0493bd;
margin-top: -4px;
color: white;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
letter-spacing: .1em;
padding-top: 22px;
padding-bottom: 22px;
font-weight: 500;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s;
-o-transition: all 0.3s;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s;
transition: all 0.3s;
text-align:center;
}

/* Change text color & background opacity on hover*/
#button-blue:hover{
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
color: #0493bd;
}
#button-blue:after{content:">>"}

 /* The white hover effect */
.ease {
width: 0px;
height: 70px;
background-color: white;
-webkit-transition: .3s ease;
-moz-transition: .3s ease;
-o-transition: .3s ease;
-ms-transition: .3s ease;
transition: .3s ease;
}

 /* Make visable when hover */
.btn-container:hover .ease{
width: 100%;
max-width: 500px;
background-color: white;
border: 0;
}


.btn-container:after {

display: none !important;
}
```

demo link

https://jsfiddle.net/0zctLenb/

Comment: thanks for the solution to a href. But this is not so much the problem. The problem is a predefined layout for a linkbutton. This forces a button to use a certain layout. When I use CSS to style a button, it will mix with the predefined layout making it look wrong and mess everything up. I can't seem to delete this predefined layout in this specific code. It did work in another css button where i used this code to override the layout: .threeCol .Normal a.button2:after
{
    content: "";
    font-size: 1.3em;
}